# Como obter o código de uma Categoria Geral Unicode?

Tags: java, unicode

Java possui o método [`Character.getType(char)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getType%28char%29) para obter a [Categoria Geral Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category) de um caracter, porém o valor de retorno é um `int` - correspondendo a uma constante definida na própria classe `Character` (ex.: `public static final byte LOWERCASE_LETTER` - 'General category "Ll" in the Unicode specification.'). Eu preciso do [**código**](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm) dessa categoria, no formato string (ex.: `"Ll"`).

Existe um meio de converter das constantes do `Character` para esse código em string? Ou tenho que fazer o mapeamento manualmente? (i.e. mapear [cada constante numérica](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang) ao seu código - tal como descrito na documentação - não tão difícil, mas trabalhoso e sujeito a erros)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não conheço nenhuma função que retorne o valor como String como você quer.
E, baseando em vários projetos que pesquisei no github, a solução encontrada geralmente envolve um mapeamento que, como você mesmo disse, é mais trabalhoso e sujeito a erros.

Mas, de qualquer forma fica uma sugestão de solução:

```
private static HashMap<Byte, String> type_aliases;
static 
{
    type_aliases = new HashMap<Byte, String>(30);
    type_aliases.put(Character.UNASSIGNED, "Cn");
    type_aliases.put(Character.UPPERCASE_LETTER, "Lu");
    type_aliases.put(Character.LOWERCASE_LETTER, "Ll");
    type_aliases.put(Character.TITLECASE_LETTER, "Lt");
    type_aliases.put(Character.MODIFIER_LETTER, "Lm");
    type_aliases.put(Character.OTHER_LETTER, "Lo");
    type_aliases.put(Character.NON_SPACING_MARK, "Mn");
    type_aliases.put(Character.ENCLOSING_MARK, "Me");
    type_aliases.put(Character.COMBINING_SPACING_MARK, "Mc");
    type_aliases.put(Character.DECIMAL_DIGIT_NUMBER, "Nd");
    type_aliases.put(Character.LETTER_NUMBER, "Nl");
    type_aliases.put(Character.OTHER_NUMBER, "No");
    type_aliases.put(Character.SPACE_SEPARATOR, "Zs");
    type_aliases.put(Character.LINE_SEPARATOR, "Zl");
    type_aliases.put(Character.PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR, "Zp");
    type_aliases.put(Character.CONTROL, "Cc");
    type_aliases.put(Character.FORMAT, "Cf");
    type_aliases.put(Character.PRIVATE_USE, "Co");
    type_aliases.put(Character.SURROGATE, "Cs");
    type_aliases.put(Character.DASH_PUNCTUATION, "Pd");
    type_aliases.put(Character.START_PUNCTUATION, "Ps");
    type_aliases.put(Character.END_PUNCTUATION, "Pe");
    type_aliases.put(Character.CONNECTOR_PUNCTUATION, "Pc");
    type_aliases.put(Character.OTHER_PUNCTUATION, "Po");
    type_aliases.put(Character.MATH_SYMBOL, "Sm");
    type_aliases.put(Character.CURRENCY_SYMBOL, "Sc");
    type_aliases.put(Character.MODIFIER_SYMBOL, "Sk");
    type_aliases.put(Character.OTHER_SYMBOL, "So");
    type_aliases.put(Character.INITIAL_QUOTE_PUNCTUATION, "Pi");
    type_aliases.put(Character.FINAL_QUOTE_PUNCTUATION, "Pf");
}
```

E chamando o método:

```
    public static String getTypeStr(char ch)
    {
        return type_aliases.get((byte) Character.getType(ch));
    }
```

Então:

```
 String ch_str = getTypeStr(','); // Retorna "Po"
```

Answer (score 1):

Não creio que exista um método pronto dentro do Java para realizar isso automaticamente. A melhor solução é a implementação manual.

Apenas aproveitando o tópico, para constar como referência futura para outros usuários, já me deparei com o mesmo problema, só que em outra linguagem: JavaScript.

Na época, minha solução foi adaptar a implementação do Mono (C#) para JavaScript, através desses três links (vale mencionar que os valores das constantes utilizados pelo Mono **não** são os mesmos valores das constantes utilizadas pelo Java):

[Char.cs](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/a31c107f59298053e4ff17fd09b2fa617b75c1ba/mcs/class/corlib/System/Char.cs)

[UnicodeCategory.cs](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/a31c107f59298053e4ff17fd09b2fa617b75c1ba/mcs/class/corlib/System.Globalization/UnicodeCategory.cs)

[mono-devel-list](http://marc.info/?l=mono-devel-list&m=111336488726890)

Apenas por uma questão de completude, meu código JavaScript ficou assim na época:

```
"use strict";

window.StringUtils = {
    UnicodeCategory: {
        UppercaseLetter: 0,
        LowercaseLetter: 1,
        TitlecaseLetter: 2,
        ModifierLetter: 3,
        OtherLetter: 4,
        NonSpacingMark: 5,
        SpacingCombiningMark: 6,
        EnclosingMark: 7,
        DecimalDigitNumber: 8,
        LetterNumber: 9,
        OtherNumber: 10,
        SpaceSeparator: 11,
        LineSeparator: 12,
        ParagraphSeparator: 13,
        Control: 14,
        Format: 15,
        Surrogate: 16,
        PrivateUse: 17,
        ConnectorPunctuation: 18,
        DashPunctuation: 19,
        OpenPunctuation: 20,
        ClosePunctuation: 21,
        InitialQuotePunctuation: 22,
        FinalQuotePunctuation: 23,
        OtherPunctuation: 24,
        MathSymbol: 25,
        CurrencySymbol: 26,
        ModifierSymbol: 27,
        OtherSymbol: 28,
        OtherNotAssigned: 29
    },
    UnicodeCategoryStr: [
        "UppercaseLetter",
        "LowercaseLetter",
        "TitlecaseLetter",
        "ModifierLetter",
        "OtherLetter",
        "NonSpacingMark",
        "SpacingCombiningMark",
        "EnclosingMark",
        "DecimalDigitNumber",
        "LetterNumber",
        "OtherNumber",
        "SpaceSeparator",
        "LineSeparator",
        "ParagraphSeparator",
        "Control",
        "Format",
        "Surrogate",
        "PrivateUse",
        "ConnectorPunctuation",
        "DashPunctuation",
        "OpenPunctuation",
        "ClosePunctuation",
        "InitialQuotePunctuation",
        "FinalQuotePunctuation",
        "OtherPunctuation",
        "MathSymbol",
        "CurrencySymbol",
        "ModifierSymbol",
        "OtherSymbol",
        "OtherNotAssigned"
    ],
    _highByteToSegment: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 42, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 43, 21, 21, 21, 21, 44, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 45, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 21, 48, 49, 21, 50, 51, 52, ],
    _segmentToStride: [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 48, 56, 64, 72, 72, 80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 88, 96, 104, 112, 48, 48, 120, 128, 72, 72, 136, 72, 
    144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 152, 152, 160, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 168, 176, 184, 192, 200, 208, 216, 224, 232, 240, 248, 152, 256, 144, 144, 264, 144, 
    144, 144, 144, 144, 272, 144, 280, 288, 288, 288, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 296, 304, 312, 320, 328, 320, 328, 336, 344, 288, 288, 
    352, 352, 352, 352, 352, 352, 352, 352, 352, 360, 288, 288, 368, 288, 376, 384, 392, 400, 408, 48, 416, 424, 72, 72, 72, 432, 440, 272, 144, 144, 448, 288, 
    48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 144, 144, 144, 144, 456, 464, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 472, 480, 144, 144, 144, 144, 488, 496, 
    288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 504, 48, 48, 48, 512, 520, 528, 72, 72, 72, 72, 536, 544, 352, 552, 352, 352, 560, 568, 288, 576, 576, 576, 584, 592, 288, 
    288, 600, 288, 608, 616, 576, 576, 584, 624, 632, 640, 288, 24, 648, 656, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 664, 672, 680, 688, 24, 696, 
    704, 712, 720, 576, 576, 728, 352, 352, 352, 368, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 576, 576, 576, 576, 736, 352, 744, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 
    288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 
    752, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 760, 768, 776, 784, 576, 792, 24, 800, 288, 808, 816, 824, 576, 576, 832, 840, 848, 856, 864, 872, 880, 888, 24, 896, 904, 
    912, 920, 824, 576, 576, 832, 928, 848, 936, 944, 288, 952, 960, 24, 968, 288, 752, 976, 984, 576, 576, 832, 992, 760, 1000, 1008, 1016, 288, 1024, 24, 288, 288, 
    808, 816, 824, 576, 576, 832, 1032, 1040, 1048, 864, 1056, 880, 1064, 24, 1072, 288, 1080, 1088, 1096, 1104, 1112, 1088, 1120, 1128, 1136, 1144, 872, 288, 1152, 24, 1160, 288, 
    1168, 1176, 832, 576, 576, 832, 1184, 1192, 1200, 1208, 1216, 288, 1064, 24, 288, 288, 1224, 1176, 832, 576, 576, 832, 1184, 1232, 1240, 1248, 1256, 1264, 1064, 24, 288, 288, 
    1224, 1176, 832, 576, 576, 832, 576, 1128, 1272, 1144, 872, 288, 1064, 24, 288, 288, 1224, 576, 1280, 1288, 576, 576, 984, 1296, 1280, 1304, 1312, 1320, 288, 288, 1328, 288, 
    616, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 1336, 1344, 1352, 1360, 24, 1368, 288, 288, 288, 288, 1376, 1384, 1392, 616, 1400, 1408, 1336, 1416, 1424, 640, 24, 1432, 288, 288, 288, 288, 
    1440, 704, 1448, 1456, 24, 1464, 1472, 1480, 576, 616, 576, 576, 576, 584, 544, 1488, 1496, 1504, 352, 544, 352, 352, 352, 1512, 1520, 1528, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 
    576, 576, 576, 576, 984, 1536, 1544, 1552, 24, 1560, 1568, 1576, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 48, 48, 48, 48, 1584, 288, 576, 576, 576, 576, 1280, 1592, 
    576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 1600, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 584, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 1608, 
    1280, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 1280, 1096, 1280, 1096, 576, 576, 576, 576, 1280, 1096, 576, 576, 576, 1280, 1096, 1280, 1096, 1280, 1280, 576, 576, 1280, 576, 576, 
    576, 1280, 1096, 1280, 576, 576, 576, 576, 1280, 576, 576, 584, 1616, 1624, 1464, 1632, 288, 288, 288, 288, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 728, 288, 
    616, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 
    576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 
    576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 1640, 1280, 288, 1648, 576, 576, 1656, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 1664, 1672, 288, 
    288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 1680, 1688, 1696, 768, 1704, 1712, 24, 1720, 288, 288, 
    1728, 1736, 24, 1720, 576, 576, 576, 576, 1744, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 288, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 1752, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 
    144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 1760, 448, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 144, 496, 
    72, 48, 296, 1584, 72, 48, 72, 48, 296, 1584, 72, 1768, 72, 48, 72, 296, 72, 1776, 72, 1776, 72, 1776, 1784, 1792, 1800, 1808, 1816, 1824, 72, 1832, 1840, 1848, 
    1856, 1864, 1872, 1880, 704, 1888, 704, 1896, 1904, 1912, 288, 288, 288, 1920, 1928, 1936, 1944, 1952, 288, 288, 1960, 1960, 288, 288, 288, 288, 352, 1968, 1976, 288, 288, 288, 
    1984, 1992, 2000, 2008, 2016, 2024, 2032, 2040, 288, 288, 2048, 1944, 2056, 2056, 2056, 2056, 2064, 288, 2072, 2080, 2088, 2096, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2112, 2120, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2128, 288, 
    2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2136, 2144, 288, 
    2104, 2152, 2104, 2104, 2160, 2168, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2176, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2184, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 
    2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2192, 288, 288, 288, 2104, 2184, 288, 288, 1944, 1944, 1944, 1944, 1944, 1944, 1944, 2200, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2208, 288, 288, 
    2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2216, 288, 2104, 2104, 2224, 2104, 2232, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 288, 
    2104, 2104, 2128, 2240, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2224, 2248, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 
    2256, 2264, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2240, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2272, 2280, 2192, 2240, 288, 2288, 1944, 1944, 1944, 2296, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2240, 2192, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 
    2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 
    288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2304, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2128, 288, 
    2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2216, 288, 288, 288, 2104, 2128, 
    2312, 2320, 2328, 2336, 2344, 2352, 2360, 2368, 616, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 728, 2376, 616, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 2384, 
    2392, 576, 576, 576, 576, 728, 616, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 1280, 2400, 2104, 576, 576, 576, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 
    2104, 2104, 2104, 2408, 1944, 2416, 2104, 2104, 2128, 288, 288, 288, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2424, 1944, 2416, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 1072, 288, 2104, 2128, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2192, 
    2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2192, 2432, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2216, 2104, 2104, 2104, 2192, 
    576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 2440, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 
    576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 2440, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 
    576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 728, 2104, 2104, 2264, 2104, 2176, 2104, 2448, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 
    576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 1504, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 
    2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 2456, 
    2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 2464, 
    576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 2440, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 
    432, 288, 2472, 2480, 576, 2488, 1280, 2496, 2504, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 1608, 288, 288, 288, 2512, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 
    576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 2520, 288, 288, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 1288, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 288, 288, 288, 288, 288, 576, 1504, 
    288, 288, 288, 288, 2528, 288, 2536, 2544, 2552, 2560, 2568, 2576, 2584, 2592, 2600, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 576, 2608, 
    2616, 16, 24, 32, 40, 48, 48, 56, 64, 72, 72, 2624, 2632, 576, 624, 576, 576, 576, 576, 2640, 576, 576, 576, 1280, 1288, 1288, 1288, 2648, 2656, 2664, 288, 2672 ],
    _strideData: [ 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 
    11, 24, 24, 24, 26, 24, 24, 24, 
    20, 21, 24, 25, 24, 19, 24, 24, 
    8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
    8, 8, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25, 24, 
    24, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 20, 24, 21, 27, 18, 
    27, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 20, 25, 21, 25, 14, 
    11, 24, 26, 26, 26, 26, 28, 28, 
    27, 28, 1, 22, 25, 19, 28, 27, 
    28, 25, 10, 10, 27, 1, 28, 24, 
    27, 10, 1, 23, 10, 10, 10, 24, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 25, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 25, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
    1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    0, 1, 1, 4, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 2, 1, 0, 
    2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
    1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
    29, 29, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 29, 29, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 27, 27, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
    3, 3, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 
    27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 27, 27, 27, 
    27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 3, 29, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 29, 
    5, 5, 5, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    29, 29, 29, 29, 27, 27, 29, 29, 
    29, 29, 3, 29, 29, 29, 24, 29, 
    29, 29, 29, 29, 27, 27, 0, 24, 
    0, 0, 0, 29, 0, 29, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 29, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 29, 
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    0, 1, 28, 5, 5, 5, 5, 29, 
    7, 7, 29, 29, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 29, 29, 0, 
    1, 29, 29, 0, 1, 29, 29, 29, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 29, 29, 
    0, 1, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    29, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 29, 
    29, 3, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
    29, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    29, 24, 19, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    29, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 29, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 29, 5, 5, 5, 24, 5, 
    24, 5, 5, 24, 5, 29, 29, 29, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    4, 4, 4, 24, 24, 29, 29, 29, 
    29, 29, 29, 29, 24, 29, 29, 29, 
    29, 29, 29, 24, 29, 29, 29, 24, 
    29, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 29, 29, 
    8, 8, 24, 24, 24, 24, 29, 29, 
    5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 24, 4, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 5, 
    5, 28, 5, 5, 5, 5, 29, 29, 
    8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 28, 28, 29, 
    24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
    24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 29, 15, 
    4, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 29, 29, 29, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 
    5, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    29, 5, 5, 6, 29, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 29, 29, 5, 4, 6, 6, 
    6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 29, 29, 
    4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 29, 29, 29, 
    4, 4, 5, 5, 24, 24, 8, 8, 
    24, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    29, 5, 6, 6, 29, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 29, 29, 4, 
    4, 29, 29, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 29, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 29, 4, 29, 29, 29, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 29, 29, 5, 29, 6, 6, 
    6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 29, 29, 6, 
    6, 29, 29, 6, 6, 5, 29, 29, 
    29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 6, 
    29, 29, 29, 29, 4, 4, 29, 4, 
    4, 4, 5, 5, 29, 29, 8, 8, 
    4, 4, 26, 26, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    29, 29, 5, 29, 29, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 29, 29, 29, 29, 4, 
    4, 29, 4, 4, 29, 4, 4, 29, 
    6, 5, 5, 29, 29, 29, 29, 5, 
    5, 29, 29, 5, 5, 5, 29, 29, 
    29, 4, 4, 4, 4, 29, 4, 29, 
    29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 8, 8, 
    5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 29, 29, 29, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 29, 4, 29, 4, 
    4, 4, 29, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 29, 4, 4, 29, 4, 4, 4, 
    6, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 29, 5, 
    5, 6, 29, 6, 6, 5, 29, 29, 
    4, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    4, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 8, 8, 
    4, 29, 4, 4, 29, 29, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 29, 29, 5, 4, 6, 5, 
    6, 5, 5, 5, 29, 29, 29, 6, 
    29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 5, 6, 
    4, 4, 29, 29, 29, 29, 8, 8, 
    28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    29, 29, 5, 6, 29, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 29, 29, 29, 4, 4, 
    4, 29, 4, 4, 4, 4, 29, 29, 
    29, 4, 4, 29, 4, 29, 4, 4, 
    29, 29, 29, 4, 4, 29, 29, 29, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 29, 4, 
    4, 4, 29, 29, 29, 29, 6, 6, 
    5, 6, 6, 29, 29, 29, 6, 6, 
    6, 29, 6, 6, 6, 5, 29, 29, 
    29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 8, 
    10, 10, 10, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    29, 6, 6, 6, 29, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 29, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 29, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 29, 29, 29, 29, 5, 5, 
    5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 29, 5, 5, 
    5, 29, 5, 5, 5, 5, 29, 29, 
    29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 5, 5, 29, 
    29, 29, 6, 6, 29, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 29, 29, 29, 29, 6, 5, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 29, 5, 6, 
    6, 29, 6, 6, 5, 5, 29, 29, 
    29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 6, 6, 29, 
    29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 4, 29, 
    6, 5, 5, 5, 29, 29, 6, 6, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 29, 
    29, 29, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 29, 4, 29, 29, 
    29, 29, 5, 29, 29, 29, 29, 6, 
    6, 6, 5, 5, 5, 29, 5, 29, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
    29, 29, 6, 6, 24, 29, 29, 29, 
    4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 29, 29, 29, 29, 26, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 24, 
    8, 8, 24, 24, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    29, 4, 4, 29, 4, 29, 29, 4, 
    4, 29, 4, 29, 29, 4, 29, 29, 
    29, 29, 29, 29, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    29, 4, 4, 4, 29, 4, 29, 4, 
    29, 29, 4, 4, 29, 4, 4, 4, 
    5, 5, 29, 5, 5, 4, 29, 29, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 29, 3, 29, 
    8, 8, 29, 29, 4, 4, 29, 29, 
    4, 28, 28, 28, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
    24, 24, 24, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
    5, 5, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
    8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 28, 5, 28, 5, 
    28, 5, 20, 21, 20, 21, 6, 6, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 24, 5, 5, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 29, 28, 28, 
    28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 5, 28, 
    28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 28, 
    29, 4, 4, 29, 6, 5, 5, 5, 
    5, 6, 5, 29, 29, 29, 5, 5, 
    6, 5, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    8, 8, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 
    5, 5, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 29, 29, 
    29, 29, 29, 24, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    4, 4, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 4, 
    4, 4, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    29, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
    24, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 29, 29, 29, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 24, 24, 4, 
    11, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 20, 21, 29, 29, 29, 
    4, 4, 4, 24, 24, 24, 10, 10, 
    10, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 5, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 
    6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
    24, 24, 24, 26, 24, 29, 29, 29, 
    8, 8, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 19, 24, 
    24, 24, 24, 15, 15, 15, 15, 29, 
    4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 5, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    29, 0, 29, 0, 29, 0, 29, 0, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 29, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 27, 1, 27, 
    27, 27, 1, 1, 1, 29, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 27, 27, 27, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 29, 29, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 29, 27, 27, 27, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27, 27, 27, 
    29, 29, 1, 1, 1, 29, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 27, 27, 29, 
    11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
    11, 11, 11, 11, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
    19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 24, 24, 
    22, 23, 20, 22, 22, 23, 20, 22, 
    12, 13, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 11, 
    24, 22, 23, 24, 24, 24, 24, 18, 
    18, 24, 24, 24, 25, 20, 21, 29, 
    24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 29, 29, 
    29, 29, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
    10, 29, 29, 29, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 25, 25, 25, 20, 21, 1, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 25, 25, 25, 20, 21, 29, 
    26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 
    7, 5, 7, 7, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    28, 28, 0, 28, 28, 28, 28, 0, 
    28, 28, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
    0, 0, 0, 1, 28, 0, 28, 28, 
    28, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28, 28, 
    28, 28, 28, 28, 0, 28, 0, 28, 
    0, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0, 28, 1, 
    0, 0, 28, 0, 1, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 1, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    29, 29, 29, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
    9, 9, 9, 9, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 28, 28, 28, 
    28, 28, 25, 25, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
    25, 28, 28, 25, 28, 28, 25, 28, 
    28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 25, 28, 
    28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
    28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 25, 25, 
    28, 28, 25, 28, 25, 28, 28, 28, 
    28, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 
    25, 25, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    25, 25, 25, 25, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
    25, 25, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
    28, 20, 21, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
    28, 28, 28, 28,  29, 28, 
    29, 29, 29, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 29, 29, 
    28, 29, 28, 28, 28, 29, 28, 29, 
    16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 
    17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 
    29, 29, 29, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 4, 5, 4, 
    4, 25, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 29, 4, 29, 
    4, 4, 29, 4, 4, 29, 4, 4, 
    29, 29, 29, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 20, 21, 
    5, 5, 5, 5, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    24, 19, 19, 18, 18, 20, 21, 20, 
    21, 20, 21, 20, 21, 20, 21, 20, 
    21, 20, 21, 20, 21, 29, 29, 29, 
    29, 24, 24, 24, 24, 18, 18, 18, 
    24, 24, 24, 29, 24, 24, 24, 24, 
    19, 20, 21, 20, 21, 20, 21, 24, 
    24, 24, 25, 19, 25, 25, 25, 29, 
    24, 26, 24, 24, 29, 29, 29, 29, 
    4, 4, 4, 29, 4, 29, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 29, 29, 15, 
    29, 24, 24, 24, 26, 24, 24, 24, 
    1, 1, 1, 20, 25, 21, 25, 29, 
    29, 24, 20, 21, 24, 18, 4, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 
    29, 29, 4, 4, 4, 29, 29, 29, 
    26, 26, 25, 27, 28, 26, 26, 29, 
    28, 25, 25, 25, 25, 28, 28, 29, 
    29, 15, 15, 15, 28, 28, 29, 29 ],
    getUnicodeCategory: function (c) {
        var seg = StringUtils._highByteToSegment[c >>> 8],
        stride = StringUtils._segmentToStride[((c & 0xFF) >>> 3) + (seg << 5)];
        return StringUtils._strideData[(c & 0x07) + stride];
    },
    getUnicodeCategoryStr: function (c) {
        var seg = StringUtils._highByteToSegment[c >>> 8],
        stride = StringUtils._segmentToStride[((c & 0xFF) >>> 3) + (seg << 5)];
        return StringUtils.UnicodeCategoryStr[StringUtils._strideData[(c & 0x07) + stride]];
    },
    isWhiteSpace: function (x) {
        switch (x) {
            case 0x0020:
            case 0x0009:
            case 0x000A:
            case 0x000B:
            case 0x000D:
            case 0x000C:
            case 0x0085:
            case 0x00A0:
            case 0x1680:
            case 0x180E:
            case 0x2000:
            case 0x2001:
            case 0x2002:
            case 0x2003:
            case 0x2004:
            case 0x2005:
            case 0x2006:
            case 0x2007:
            case 0x2008:
            case 0x2009:
            case 0x200A:
            case 0x202F:
            case 0x205F:
            case 0x3000:
            case 0x2028:
            case 0x2029:
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    },
    isDigit: function (c) {
        return (StringUtils.getUnicodeCategory(c) === StringUtils.UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber);
    },
    isLetter: function (c) {
        return (StringUtils.getUnicodeCategory(c) <= StringUtils.UnicodeCategory.OtherLetter);
    },
    isLetterOrDigit: function (c) {
        var category = StringUtils.getUnicodeCategory(c);
        return (category <= StringUtils.UnicodeCategory.OtherLetter ||
            category === StringUtils.UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber);
    },
    isNumber: function (c) {
        var category = StringUtils.getUnicodeCategory(c);
        return (category >= StringUtils.UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber &&
            category <= StringUtils.UnicodeCategory.OtherNumber);
    },
    isSurrogate: function (c) {
        return (StringUtils.getUnicodeCategory(c) === StringUtils.UnicodeCategory.Surrogate);
    }
}
Object.freeze(StringUtils.UnicodeCategory);
Object.freeze(StringUtils.UnicodeCategoryStr);
Object.freeze(StringUtils);
```

Comment: Embora isso não responda à pergunta, achei bastante útil, +1. Você saberia dizer se essa solução cobre todo o BMP? (ou, se vai além do BMP, melhor ainda)

Comment: Essa adaptação para JavaScript cobre apenas o BMP inteiro (U+0000 até U+FFFF), por causa tanto da tabela utilizada (que foi amplamente otimizada pela pessoa no 3o link que eu postei), como por causa da minha função `getUnicodeCategory`, que trata apenas um caractere isolado. Para ir além, seria necessário detectar os pares de surrogates, e converte-los (conforme necessário) para utf32, e então executar a conversão da linha 228 do arquivo Char.cs (1o link que eu postei), utilizando a tabela `category_astral_index`, que não foi portada para essa adaptação em JavaScript.